# Remote control a computer using another computer

Tags: windows-7, remote-control

I've got a main desktop computer at home, I'd like watch movies using it but able to control it afar.

For example, I would like to lay on my bed and control the desktop using my own laptop via wireless.

I've been looking for solutions to my question. I tried to use remote desktop, I can pause the movie but I then have to go to the pc to log in the OS again. I also tried to bind my desktop to my mobile phone over bluetooth, this works as I can control the mouse etc. but I found I can barely see the mouse pointer when at long distance.

I still wish I can use my laptop as a remote control, is this possible?

Comment: SNAP! I win! :)

Comment: got an iPhone handy?

Answer (score 8):

The program you want is [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/). I personally have used it exactly as you describe.

Here's an explanatory picture from their website:

[image: synergy]

So you would set up your laptop as the server, and your desktop as a client.

If you have problems seeing the mouse cursor on the far away monitor, I'd suggest you simply increase the pointer size in the control panel.

Comment: Haha, yay, I made that image. +1 for using it! :)

Comment: +1 for synergy, use it every day for a windows/linux system, thing is a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

For minimal configuration, I recommend [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx). It will not log you out like RDC.

Comment: simply the best ...

Comment: Teamviewer is great - I use it all the time, but maybe Synergy+ is better when you can physically see the remote computer's screen. I am bias though, of course.

Answer (score 1):

VNC: http://www.realvnc.com/

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for Windows Media Center computers that allows you to send commands from one computer over ethernet or wifi that are interpreted by the other computer as if they came from a media center remote.   I don't think that it's really necessary for the destination computer to be a Windows media center PC. It's called [MCE Controller](http://www.kindel.com/products/mcecontroller/)

Source is available via [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcecontroller/)

Havn't played with it yet myself, it's on my todo pile :)